# JS: How to print a value from a text box into the screen?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I want to print a value onto the screen based on text in the input (textbox) in the form.

```
<input type="text" name="pesos" value="">
<button onclick="conversorMonedas()">Convertir!</button>
<p id="resultado"></p>

function conversorMonedas() {
    var pesos = document.getElementById("pesos");
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = pesos.value;
}
```

When I click the button, the error at the console appears briefly and then disappears. I managed to read it and it says that `pesos.value` is null.

How can I print out what I wrote in the text box? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have element with id pesos. Add id to your input:

```
<input type="text" name="pesos" id="pesos" value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

By using

```
 var pesos = document.getElementById("pesos");
```

You're querying for something that has the `id` property set to `pesos`, looking at your HTML code you're not setting the `id` of your `<input>`

Simply add it, it should be like this:

```
<input type="text" id="pesos" name="pesos" value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no element with id pesos. So either add id="pesos" to input or modify your function to use getElementByNames as

```
$scope.conversorMonedas = function() {
    var pesos = document.getElementsByName("pesos")[0];
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = pesos.value;
}
```

But this may not work in cases you have multiple elements with this same name

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input id="input" type="text" name="text">

function Val() {
  var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
  document.getElementById("print1").innerHTML = x;
 
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="input" type="text" name="box">
  <button id="btn" type="button" name="button" 
        onclick="Vale()">Post</button>
   <span id="print1"></span>    


var post = []
    function Vale() {
      const val = document.querySelector('input').value;
      document.getElementById('input').value = "";
      console.log(val);
      post.push(val)
      document.getElementById('print1').innerHTML = val
      console.log(post);
    }
```

Comment: if you want store the input value in an array then print on the page so on that case this code will work fine. –